# Glassfish 5.1.0 error when adding resources from web console

Tags: glassfish

Glassfish server up and running. I want to add some data source, and do it from web console->Resources.

Click button "Add Resources" then choose file from my computer (same to the file from server) and click OK. GUI gives me error:

**An error has occurred
The system cannot find the path specified:**

In log I get:

> [2019-11-20T12:26:23.149+0300] [glassfish 5.1] [INFO] []
>   [org.glassfish.admingui] [tid: _ThreadID=69
>   _ThreadName=admin-listener(3)] [timeMillis: 1574241983149] [levelValue: 800] [[   GUI deployment: uploadToTempfile]]
>
> [2019-11-20T12:26:23.165+0300] [glassfish 5.1] [SEVERE] []
>   [org.glassfish.admingui] [tid: _ThreadID=69
>   _ThreadName=admin-listener(3)] [timeMillis: 1574241983165] [levelValue: 1000] [[   RestResponse.getResponse() gives
>   FAILURE.  endpoint =
>   'https://localhost:4848/management/domain/resources/add-resources';
>   attrs = '{id=,
>   target=mdmcluster}']]

Please, give any ideas how to fix this issue.

Comment: What file exactly are you trying to upload? It seems that something is not right with the file because the error message shows an empty id: ```'{id=, target=mdmcluster}'```

Comment: An XML file with resource definition

Comment: Maybe you should show the content of the file. Maybe it does not follow the format that Glassfish expects? Or did that file work at some time?

Comment: @ChristophJohn, you are right. I messed up with format. Please, give right format for the xml file as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct format for the `glassfish-resources.xml` file is outlined in the Glassfish Application Deployment Guide page 191. It can be downloaded here: https://javaee.github.io/glassfish/doc/5.0/application-deployment-guide.pdf

Here is an example for defining a JDBC connection pool:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE resources PUBLIC "-//GlassFish.org//DTD GlassFish Application Server 3.1 Resource Definitions//EN" "http://glassfish.org/dtds/glassfish-resources_1_5.dtd">
<resources>

    <!-- Connects to MySql database called 'test' on a server called 'database' -->
    <jdbc-connection-pool name="jdbc/testConnPool"
                          res-type="javax.sql.DataSource"
                          datasource-classname="com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource"
                          pool-resize-quantity="2"
                          max-pool-size="32"
                          steady-pool-size="8">
        <property name="URL" value="jdbc:mysql://database:3306/test"/>
        <property name="User" value="root"/>
        <property name="Password" value="password"/>
    </jdbc-connection-pool>

    <jdbc-resource enabled="true" jndi-name="jdbc/testDS" object-type="user" pool-name="jdbc/testConnPool">
        <description>Test DataSource jdbc/testDS for Connection Pool jdbc/testConnPool</description>
    </jdbc-resource>

</resources>
```

Taken from https://github.com/payara/Payara-Examples/blob/master/payara-micro/database-ping/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/glassfish-resources.xml

Comment: Thank you! I added resource by asadmin, but still cannot add by web console. May be its bug in web